# php gzfile not working

Tags: php, compression

This is working fine: **readgzfile($filename)**;

This is ***not*** working: **gzfile($filename)**;

*gzfile function outputs this error*:

```
Warning: gzfile(http://www.example.com/abc.xml.gz): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.
```

I checked my **php.ini** and **phpinfo** and found nothing is disabled!

I have verified with if (function_exists('gzfile')) to make sure it's available. 503 or any other error isn't taking place for readgzfile function!

This is a Windows 2008 server and PHP is 5.3.23.

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Have you given readable permission to file?

Comment: @Manwal yes I did, that's why readgzfile is working fine.

Comment: Try once this gzfile($filename,1)

Comment: @vijay4vijju I just tried, same result bro.